# Response data - {"error":"invalid_grant"}

Tags: jmeter

I am testing web app and for the page URL `http://www.....webApi/token` it shows the Response data:

> {"error":"invalid_grant"}

1. I like to know how to overcome invalid_grant in JMeter step by step; OR
2. Does developer need to fix something on the server with refresh tokens?

#### Request

#### Response

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt anyone here will be able to provide "step by step" instructions, the overall idea regarding the authentication flow you can get from i.e. [Authorize access to web applications using OAuth 2.0 and Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) guide.

With regards to JMeter specifics the options of bypassing [OAuth](https://oauth.net/) challenge are described in [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter)

If you are able to reproduce the issue using real web browser or i.e. [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/) tool - report this issue to developers, otherwise you will need to fix your JMeter test.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitri T  thanks for guidance.

With my question I found from developer that URL request - response is failure because of the regeneration of the same token. I just disable it from the JMeter that specific request from the test case.